# Paypal REST integration - no error, but payment not processed

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

After some other issues we managed to go live with the PayPal REST integration. Sandbox works fine, by the way, so we assume that the code is o.k.

Well this is what happened on live System:

- My first customer initiated her first payment via paypal.
- The payment request shows as successfully executed on the Paypal Dashboard. No error!
- But the customer always got the message that something is wrong with their creditcard.
- According to Paypal customer support the credit Card is fine (and the customer successfully made other payments using the same credit Card with Paypal) but that somthing must be wrong with the payment request.
- But as mentioned above I cannot see an error in the dashboard nor in the logfile.
- Paypal Tech Support is not responding (since over a week), so maybe somebody here has seen this before and can advise?

Thanks a lot

Christoph

Comment: Do you noticed any money flew into your account?

Comment: No, My customer was not able to complete the payment.